# Case...When...In a WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

My code, as I thought it would work, is as follows:

```
WHERE cp.OwnerId = 1
AND CASE
    WHEN [CustAccountNote] <> 'n/a' AND [CustRulesDocPath] <> 'n/a' 
    THEN (cp.NAME = 'IQRRulesLinks' OR cp.NAME = 'AccountNote')
END 
AND pp.lastupdated BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND GETDATE()
```

Inevitably what I want to do is OMIT what is in the THEN statement if [CustAccountNote] and [CustRulesDocPath] are both 'n/a'.
T-SQL doesn't like what I'm doing.  (shocker).

How would I write this WHERE statement so that if BOTH of those field results are 'n/a', it won't run the "cp.Name = ....." ?

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** that can return a value - it cannot be used to conditionally execute code blocks / statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
WHERE cp.OwnerId = 1
  AND (    ([CustAccountNote] = 'n/a' AND [CustRulesDocPath] = 'n/a')
        or (cp.NAME = 'IQRRulesLinks' OR cp.NAME = 'AccountNote')
      )
  AND pp.lastupdated BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND GETDATE()
```

So, if **both** of `CustAccountNote` and `CustRulesDocPath` is equal to 'n/a', then it doesn't matter what values `cp.name` have.

Or, if **any** of `CustAccountNote` and `CustRulesDocPath` is NOT equal to 'n/a', then `cp.name` has to be either 'IQRRulesLinks' or 'AccountNote'.

Comment: This one seemed to do the trick, although I'll probably try the others as well.
I had to NOT use the alias of [CustAccountNote] or [CustRulesDocPath] and instead used the field name itself.  I'm now getting the results I was looking for.
Thanks, all.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it exactly as you want, since the Case can only return a single value, but you *could* hack it:

```
WHERE cp.OwnerId = 1
AND 
(
    cp.NAME = 'IQRRulesLinks' 
    OR cp.NAME = 'AccountNote'
    Or 1 =  CASE
                WHEN [CustAccountNote] = 'n/a' AND [CustRulesDocPath] = 'n/a' Then 1
                Else 0
            End
)
AND pp.lastupdated BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND GETDATE()
```

Essentially, here you are saying that either Name must equal IQRRulesLinks, or the Name must equal Name *or* 1 must equal a value determined by the Case statement. When CustAccountNote is n/a, or CustRulesDocPath is n/a, that value is 1 - effectively short circuiting the entire bracketed where clause.

Comment: This an ugly hack that I use all the time. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with `AND` & `OR` in the `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE cp.OwnerId = 1
AND (([CustAccountNote] <> 'n/a' AND [CustRulesDocPath] <> 'n/a' 
    AND (cp.NAME = 'IQRRulesLinks' OR cp.NAME = 'AccountNote'))
    OR 
    ([CustAccountNote] = 'n/a' AND [CustRulesDocPath] = 'n/a'))
AND pp.lastupdated BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND GETDATE()
```

Check [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0fc5/1) with sample data

Answer (score 0):

Based on the author's requirement that the two name conditions not be evaluated if the two other columns are not n/a, this case statement will correctly implement the requested shortcut style of logic and is the only way I know of personally to accomplish this task. Additionally as the name is based on two equivalent comparisons, the use of the IN operator is a simpler way to write that particular segment.

```
WHERE cp.OwnerId = 1
  AND (CASE
    WHEN [CustAccountNote] <> 'n/a' AND [CustRulesDocPath] <> 'n/a' 
      THEN 1
    WHEN cp.NAME IN ('IQRRulesLinks', 'AccountNote')
      THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) = 1
  AND pp.lastupdated BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: David, thanks for helping out.  I tried this route & when I parse it, I get:
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
    Invalid column name 'CustAccountNote'.
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
    Invalid column name 'CustRulesDocPath'.
It appears to not be digging my aliases or something.

Comment: @JohnWaclawski I copied your example in the question exactly. I don't have the rest of the query like the SELECT and FROM. I'd say make sure the table you're targeting there is in your FROM statement.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, `A => B` is equivalent to `(NOT A) OR B`. Thus, you can rewrite your SQL as follows:

```
WHERE cp.OwnerId = 1
AND ([CustAccountNote] = 'n/a'
    OR [CustRulesDocPath] = 'n/a'
    OR cp.NAME = 'IQRRulesLinks' 
    OR cp.NAME = 'AccountNote')
AND pp.lastupdated BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: This give wrong result if he want show only rows with both columns `CustAccountNote` and `CustRulesDocPath` having `'n/a'`

Comment: @Fabio: That depends on what he wants. His question text (ignore THEN if both are n/a) does not match his SQL example (ignore THEN if any of them is n/a).

Answer (score 0):

```
I have replaced the last part of `THEN` Statement with `Coalesce` function.


  WHERE cp.OwnerId = 1
    AND (CASE
        WHEN [CustAccountNote] <> 'n/a' AND [CustRulesDocPath] <> 'n/a'
           THEN cp.NAME = COALESCE(cp.NAME,'IQRRulesLinks', 'AccountNote')
    END )
    AND pp.lastupdated BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND GETDATE()
```